# pair multiple y-value lists with a single x-value list

Tags: list, tuples, wolfram-mathematica

I've got multiple lists, which each correspond to the chemical concentration of some species over 49 time-steps of some simulated chemical reaction. I also have a list of system temperature values at each of these same 49 time-steps. I'm trying to plot all of these chemical species lists (there are 19 of them) on the y axis, agains temperature as the x axis. However I cant figure out how to plot more than one at a time against temperature. I can only plot more than one at a time if i use an arbitrary x axis. So far I have:

```
runstats = Import["file.csv"]
t = runstats[[1, All]]

element = Import["file.csv"]
e = element[[#, 2 ;; -1]] &
f = element[[#, 1]] &
```

t is temperature, e is the list of all 49 element values, and f is the species name associated with the particular values.

so to plot them, I use.

```
a = MapThread[{#, #2} &, {t, e[1]}]
ListLinePlot[a]
```

This plots correctly for the one value of e. However I cannot insert the range `[1;;19]` into `e[1;;19]`, to plot all 19 chemical species.

Any thoughts?   Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recapping your code as understood:

```
t = {3, 4, 6, 8};(* Temps *)
element = {
  {2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
  {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
  {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}};

e = element[[#, 2 ;; -1]] &;
f = element[[#, 1]] &;

e[1](* first series of element values at temps *)
```

> {3, 4, 5, 6}

```
a = MapThread[{#, #2} &, {t, e[1]}]
```

> {{3, 3}, {4, 4}, {6, 5}, {8, 6}}

```
ListLinePlot[a]
```

[image]

To process all element series at once:

```
a = MapThread[Transpose[{#, #2}] &,
  {ConstantArray[t, Length[element]], Rest /@ element}];
```

or

```
len = Length[element];
a = MapThread[Transpose[{#, #2}] &,
  {ConstantArray[t, len], e /@ Range[len]}];

ListLinePlot[a]
```

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated !    Works beautifully . .